# How to get html from current tab to popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I use `document.body.outerHTML` to get html from a tab, but I can't do it

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "name": "SEO Analytic",
    "description": "Adds a print button to the browser.",
    "version": "1.2",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js":      ["content.js"]
        }
    ],

    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "SEO Analytic",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

**popup.js:**

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getText"}, function(response) {
        if (response.method == "getText") {
            alltext = response.data;
            alert(alltext);
        }
    });
});
```

**content.js:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "getText") {
        sendResponse({
            data: document.body.outerHTML,
            method: "getText"   // same as innerText
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try my proposed solution beliw ? Did if work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem is that you are using some deprecated features. Specificaly, using your code, I get the following errors in the console log:

> Error in response to tabs.getSelected: Error: sendRequest and onRequest are obsolete. Please use sendMessage and onMessage instead.

Although some of the deprecated stuff are possibly still supported, they sure won't be for long, so it is a good idea migrate to up-to-date APIs and methods. Namely:

- Instead of **chrome.tabs.getSelected** use **[chrome.tabs.query](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query)**.
- Instead of **chrome.tabs.sendRequest** use **[chrome.tabs.sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage)**.
- Instead of **chrome.extension.onRequest** use **[chrome.runtime.onMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage)**.

For a detailed answer on how to get some HTML content from a tab to the popup (or background page), see **[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641042/undefined-response-from-content-script-in-chrome-extension/19644584#19644584)** to a related question.

---

BTW, if you are not using `background.js`, you can remove the "background" key from the manifest altogether.